# Why jmp instruction after a lock add has so many counts for the cycles event?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, perf

I have a function GetObj(int), which take a param means vector index, here's my c++ code

```
std::shared_ptr<Obj> GetObj(int obj_id) {

    // obj_buffer_ is array, 2-buffers, 
    // declare as std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obj>> obj_buffer_[2];
    // cur_buffer_ is a atomic<size_t> var, value may be 0 or 1
    auto& vec_obj = obj_buffer_[cur_buffer_.load(std::memory_order_acquire)]; 

    // let's assume that obj_id is never illegal in running time, so program never return nullptr
    if (obj_id < 0 || obj_id >= vec_obj.size()) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    // vec_obj[obj_id] is a shared_ptr<Obj>, 
    return vec_obj[obj_id];
}
```

I will call this function 5 million times per second, and use "perf top" to see which instruction cost most, here is the result
[image: perf top]

please ignor function & vars name(GetShard is GetObj), I change the func & var's name make it easier to understand

here is my Question, let's pay attention to the last instruction

```
       │    ↓ je     6f
  0.12 │      lock   addl   $0x1,0x8(%rdx)     ............... (1)
 91.85 │   ┌──jmp    73                        ............... (2)
       │6f:│  addl   $0x1,0x8(%rdx)            ............... (3)
  0.12 │73:└─→pop    %rbp                      ............... (4)
       │    ← retq                             ............... (5)
```

I found the (1) instruction, which is shared_ptr's counter incr 1, the atomic counter incr will lock the cpu bus, then jump to (4) pop %rbp which means pop stack. these instruction is doing "return" job.
but why does jmp instruction took 90% cpu circles? the function is called 5 millions times/s, I can understand if "lock addl" slow, but why jmp instruction take so long?

Comment: Almost certainly that cost is really due to the `lock add` atomic increment.  HW perf counters tend to skew the blame; CPUs are pipelined and out-of-order so it's non-trivial to decide which instruction to account a cycle to when an event fires.

Comment: Compare against a function without lock, even if the result is wrong, only to see the effect if no lock instruction is emitted. I *believe* that jmp will be "faster".